# How to make a choice of one of the group elements of mixed inputs?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors, radio-button, dom-traversal

How to make a choice of one of the group elements of mixed inputs?

I have following code:

```
<div class="item">
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="value1">Value1</input>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="value2">Value2</input>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="value3">Value3</input>
  <textarea name="group1"></textarea>
</div>
  <div class="item">
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="value1">Value1</input>
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="value2">Value2</input>
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="value3">Value3</input>
  <textarea name="group2"></textarea>
</div>
```

I think about: when we click on textarea, radiobuttons should lost `checked` atribure.
Like:

```
$('.item textarea').on('click', function(){
  $($(this).parent + 'input[type="radio":checked]').each(function(){
    $(this).checked = false;
  });
});
```

But it not work. 
I think the problem with `parent` object. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many problems in your variant. First, there is a problem in your selector construction: `$($(this).parent + 'input[type="radio":checked]')`. Here you mix jQuery object with the string selector which is not correct. Moreover, parent element is taken with method `parent()` but not a property. Then, jQuery object doesn't have `checked` attribute.

Taking into consideration all the problems described we can get this workable code:

```
$('.item textarea').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings(":radio").prop("checked", false);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/TEk9c/

By the way, if you need to uncheck all radios when the user enters `textarea` not only using mouse `click` but using keyboard, you can use `focus` event instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to base it on the `name` attribute, you can use the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('.item textarea').on('click', function() {
    $(':radio[name="' + this.name + '"]').prop("checked", false);
});
```

If the radio buttons you need will always be in the same `div.item`, you can even write a stricter solution. In this example, first we find the closest parent that has the class `item`, and inside it we search for the radios with the same `name` attribute.

```
$('.item textarea').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.item')
        .find(':radio[name="' + this.name + '"]')
            .prop("checked", false);
});
```

**One validity note**: `<input>` is a [*void element*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element), it cannot have contents inside and a closing attribute. You have to use a [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label) element to give it a, hm, label:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="value1" /> Value1</label>
```

[jsFiddle Demo with labels added](http://jsfiddle.net/VhTuU/)

Comment: Regarding the validity note, it really depends on the `DOCTYPE`.

Comment: @VisioN In which DOCTYPE would `<input>xy</input>` be valid?

Comment: Ah, yeah... I absolutely missed that part of code :) Sorry for that!

Comment: True. I missed `name`. Thanks.